# Adding labels to individual % inside geom_bar() using R / ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
bgraph <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = location)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = success))
```

`success` is a percentage calculated as a factor of 4 categories with the varying 4 outcomes of the data set. I could separately calculate them easily, but as the `ggplot` is currently constituted, they are generated by the `geom_bar(aes(fill=success))`.

```
data <- as.data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,
                        4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7))
data[["success"]] <- c("a","b","c","c","d","d","a","b","b","b","c","d",
                       "a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","a","b","c","d",
                       "a","b","c","c","d","d","a","b","b","c","d")
names(data) <- c("location","success")
bgraph <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = location)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = success))
bgraph
```

How do I get labels over the individual percentages? More specifically, I wanted 4 individual percentages for each bar. One for yellow, light orange, orange, and red, respectively. %'s all add up to 1.

[image: Bar Graph]

Comment: please include a sample of your data to make this question reproducible

Comment: I may not understand what you're after, but will `position = 'fill'` do the trick? `geom_bar(aes(fill = success), position = 'fill')`

Comment: @AHart, no that justifies the chart to 100% of the chart area. My goal is to have percentage labels hovering over the respective colors of each individual bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a way to do this in `ggplot` directly but with some pre-processing in `dplyr`, you'll be able to achieve your desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  count(location, success) %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x = location, n, fill = success,label = paste0(round(n, 2), "%")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ronak, this is perfect

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a summary frame with the relative frequencies within `location` and then using that with `geom_col()` and `geom_text()`?

```
# Create summary stats
tots <-
  data %>%
  group_by(location,success) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n()
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    rel = round(100*n/sum(n)),
  )

# Plot
ggplot(data = tots, aes(x = location, y = n)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = fct_rev(success))) + # could only get it with this reversed
  geom_text(aes(label = rel), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

OUTPUT:
[image: Bar plot with centered labels]