# Customised bar chart in r with repeated x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the data like below that shows records of an event per weekdays,

```
    Type    Day of week
1   Week1   Tuesday
2   Week1   Tuesday
3   Week1   Wednesday
4   Week1   Friday
5   Week2   Thursday
6   Week2   Tuesday
7   Week2   Friday
8   Week2   Tuesday
9   Week2   Monday
10  Both    Thursday
11  Both    Monday
12  Both    Friday
13  Both    Thursday
14  Both    Monday
15  Both    Sunday
```

How can I have a bar plot with repeated x axis showing two weeks and plot frequencies based on Type column (both to be appeared in both weeks).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# make the "both" happen every week
both = dd %>% filter(Type == "Both") %>%
  select(-Type) %>%
  merge(data.frame(Type = c("Week1", "Week2")), by = NULL) 

# put the data together
all = dd %>% filter(Type != "Both") %>%
  bind_rows(both)

# put days in right order
all$Dayofweek = factor(all$Dayofweek, 
  levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))

# plot
ggplot(all, aes(x = Dayofweek)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~Type)
```

[image]

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(text = "    Type    Dayofweek
1   Week1   Tuesday
2   Week1   Tuesday
3   Week1   Wednesday
4   Week1   Friday
5   Week2   Thursday
6   Week2   Tuesday
7   Week2   Friday
8   Week2   Tuesday
9   Week2   Monday
10  Both    Thursday
11  Both    Monday
12  Both    Friday
13  Both    Thursday
14  Both    Monday
15  Both    Sunday", header = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- df %>%  mutate_all(as.character) %>%  mutate(Type1 = Type)

df1 %>%
   filter(Type == "Both") %>%
   tidyr::uncount(2) %>%
   mutate(Type = rep(c("Week1", "Week2"), length.out = n())) %>%
   bind_rows(df1 %>% filter(Type != "Both")) %>%
   mutate(Day_of_week = factor(Day_of_week, levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
     "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))) %>%
   ggplot() + aes(x = Day_of_week, fill = Type1) + geom_bar() +
   facet_wrap(.~Type) +
   scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Both", "Week1", 
"Week2"), class = "factor"), Day_of_week = structure(c(5L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Friday", 
"Monday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = 
"factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. What if I want to have it as Stacked bar chart with percentages?

Comment: @Sean  Do you mean something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59207281/3962914

Comment: No. Like the post below that post. So week one includes week1 ( e.g in green) and both (in red) with related percentages. And same for the week 2.

Comment: @Sean this sounds like a new question. Please post a new question including all the relevant details. Making changes in this question invalidates already existing answers and confuses future readers.

Comment: Sure. Just the bar chart but i want to see different types with different colours. :)

Comment: Sure, updated the answer to have different colors for different `Type`.

Comment: Thanks but what about type both? Type both needs to appear in both weeks and the third colour. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sean Updated the answer. Hope it solves the issue.

Comment: Yes. You are the legend.

Comment: How Can I plot the same chart if the "Type column" has several weeks, lets say Week1, ..., Week 20 without both. Can you please advise?

Comment: I am not sure and I think you have already asked a new question regarding this ?

Comment: No that's totally different topic. Just in the above data, instead of "Week 1"  and " Week 2" I have  20 week. I have manually inserted new weeks to your code in "%>%
  mutate(Type = rep(c("Week 1", "Week 2", ), length.out = n())) %>% ..." but if failed.

Comment: Found the answer from the below post. Thanks anyway